# Colocacion en plantilla de MultipleChoiceField en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Estoy haciendo una pagina web en Django y quiero introducir un MultipleChoiceField en una tabla. Lo quiero introducir de forma personalizada, pero al usar el código de plantilla no da resultados. Aquí dejo los códigos y el resultado.

- forms.py

  ```
  class paisForm(forms.Form):
      bus_pais = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
          choices=paises.objects.all().order_by('nombre').values_list('reduccion','nombre'),
          widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
          required=False,
      )
  ```
- views.py

  ```
  def index_spider_view(request):
      idiom = idiomas.objects.all().order_by('nombre')
      pais = paises.objects.all().order_by('nombre')
      continentes = paises.objects.values_list('continente', flat=True).distinct().order_by('continente')


      if request.method == "POST":
          ...
      else:
          buscador_Form = buscador_googleForm()
          idioma_Form = idiomaForm()
          pais_Form = paisForm()

      contexto = {'idioma': idiom, 'paises': pais, 'continentes': continentes, 'buscador_Form':buscador_Form,
                  'idioma_Form':idioma_Form, 'pais_Form':pais_Form}

      return render(request, 'spider_google/spider.html', contexto)
  ```
- Código HTML plantilla:

  ```
     <table class="table table-striped text-center tablapais" id="tablpais">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Seleccion</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Continente</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="id_bus_pais">
        {% for pais in pais_Form %}
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="id_bus_pais_{{pais.id_for_label}}" name="idioma_Form" value="{{pais.value}}"></td>
            <td>{{pais.id}}</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
     </table>
  ```

---

El resultado obtenido es el siguiente:

- Código HTML:

  ```
  <tbody id="id_bus_pais">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="id_bus_pais_" name="idioma_Form" value="None"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>                        
  </tbody>
  ```

[image: HTML en navegador web.]

He probado a usar `{{pais_Form.as_table}}` y funciona correctamente, pero no es lo que busco actualmente. Me gustaría si hay algún error en el código, por que no lo encuentro y no se cual es el error por el cual no muestra la tabla correctamente.

Versiones de los programas que intervienen en el codigo:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Python 3.6
- Django 2.0

---

Gracias a las respuestas en las respuestas de @F_Delgado y la documentación de Django en este [apartado](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) he conseguido obtener el resultado esperado, que era el siguiente:
[image: HTML]

El código que he seguido es el siguiente:

```
<tbody id="id_bus_pais">
 {% for pais in pais_Form.bus_pais %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{pais.tag}}</td>
    <td>{{pais.choice_label}}</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes una forma más fácil de hacerlo, te explico.

La variable `paisForm` contiene todo el formulario, dentro de esa tendrás un campo llamado pais que llamarás de esta forma `{{paisForm.pais}}` que es la que contiene el multiplecheckbox, si le haces un bucle `for` a dicha variable obtendrás todas las opciones 1 por 1 que podrás maquetar de forma individual. Te paso un ejemplo:

```
<tr>
    {% for i in paisform.pais %}
        <td>{{i}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Comment: No, no funciona y este es el resultado:
https://i.gyazo.com/4a48797b055fb8f9d1c363a1cb8c6d52.png
Lo he probando poniendo el ejemplo tal cual, cambiándolo por el nombre del Form, poniéndolo por el nombre en el diccionario de contexto y poniendo "paises" en vez de "país".

Comment: La variable de tu formulario es `pais_Form` no paisform como tengo puesto y la variable pais tampoco existe en tu formuario, es bus_pais lo que tu tienes puesto. Por otra parte has probado a pintar `{{pais_Form.bus_pais}}` tal cual? para saber que es lo que está saliendo

Comment: Ahora si muestra los resultados, pero no de la forma deseada. https://i.gyazo.com/e649891c48b0a553339d349ed91eb9b2.png .

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta con tu código

Comment: Ya esta arreglado. Muchas gracias. Fui a la documentacion de Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect y utilizando las etiquetas "tag" y "choise_label" he conseguido lo que queria. Gracias por ayudarme a encontrar el error.